# How do we solve the equation $x^{2} - 4x + 4 - i = 0$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have the following problem:

Find all the roots of $x^2 − 4x + 4 − i$ in standard form.

I have no clue where to start. I tried separating the real and imaginary parts, getting $x^2 − 4x + 4 = 0$, but obviously $-i$ doesn't equal 0.

I went along with that just to see and set $x=2-i$ after solving the real part $x^2 − 4x + 4 = 0$ and adding the $-i$ just to see where it would take me, and that didn't work.

I'm left with trying to solve $x^2 − 4x + 4 − i$ by brute force, and can't seem to find a solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: We want to solve $x^2 - 4x + 4 = i$. Do you know how to factorize the LHS?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that

\begin{align*}
x^{2} - 4x + 4 - i = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (x-2)^{2} = i = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Then you can find the solutions through the relation
\begin{align*}
z^{n} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) \Longleftrightarrow z = \cos\left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{n}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{n}\right)
\end{align*}
where $0\leq k\leq n-1$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. At your case, $\theta = \pi/2$ and $n = 2$. Can you take it from here?

**BONUS**

You can also apply the Bhaskara's formula where $a = 1$, $b = -4$ and $c = 4-i$. Thus we have that
\begin{align*}
z_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a} = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 16 + 4i}}{2} = \frac{4 \pm 2\sqrt{i}}{2} = 2\pm\sqrt{i}
\end{align*}

Comment: Gotcha. After the $(x-2)^2 = cos(\pi/2) +i sin(\pi/2)$, I ended up taking the square root of both sides to get $x-2 = +- cos(pi/4) + sin(pi/4)$ for a final answer of  $\frac{4+ \sqrt2 + i \sqrt2}{2}$ and $\frac{4- \sqrt2 - i \sqrt2}{2}$ . I'll verify that answer right now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is the quadratic formula called Bhaskara's formula? I never knew that!

Comment: Yes, at least in my country we call it so. Here it is a reference at wolframalpha: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BhaskarasFormula.html